# RecyclerView Increase Height Animation Not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I am trying to increase `RecyclerView` height on click of Button then decrease it on button click with Animation.

It is increasing and decreasing properly but animation is not working.

Here is my code.

```
public void expand(View view) {

    Button button = (Button) view;
    if(button.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("INCREASE")) {

        button.setText("DECREASE");
        final int height = (int) (recyclerView.getHeight() * 2.5);
        Animation a = new Animation() {

            @Override
            protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {

                FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp =
                        new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height);
                lp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
                recyclerView.setLayoutParams(lp);
            }
        };
        a.setDuration(2000); // in ms
        recyclerView.startAnimation(a);
    }
    else
    {

        button.setText("INCREASE");
        final int height = (int) (recyclerView.getHeight() / 2.5);
        Animation a = new Animation() {

            @Override
            protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {

                FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp =
                        new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height);
                lp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
                recyclerView.setLayoutParams(lp);
            }
        };
        a.setDuration(2000); // in ms
        recyclerView.startAnimation(a);
    }

}
```

**How do I do it ? I don't want to stretch it. I want to increase its height with some animation effect.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using value animator.

```
ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(viewToIncreaseHeight.getMeasuredHeight(), -100);
anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = viewToIncreaseHeight.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.height = val;
        viewToIncreaseHeight.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
});
anim.setDuration(DURATION);
anim.start();
```

Comment: ok after your comment. i tried valueanimator , and it worked. but its always starting animation from bottom . means when increasing height it starting animation bottom to that height of recycleview. while decreasing height recyclerview disappear and again starting from bottom to new height.

Comment: thanks it did worked. i was using 

ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, newheight);
instead of 
ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofInt(recyclerView.getHeight() , newheight);

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue, i solved it by adding the attribute `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` on the container layout in your xml layout description.
As an example:

```
<LinearLayout 
 android:id="@+id/container"
 android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
      <RecyclerView 
       android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
           ...
      />
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Some devices simply don't support this/have different animation durations or don't animate at all.